# How to use Laravel toaster package in Vue 3

Tags: php, laravel-8, vuejs3, toastr

I'm working in a project which is made in Laravel 8 and Vue 3.
I use this Laravel toastr package:

```
composer require yoeunes/toastr
```

This toaster works very fine in Laravel Controller but the problem is I don't know how to call this toaster in a vue axios function.

How can I make this toastr Global? so that I can use it in both Laravel and Vue.js sides?

I would be very happy if you could help me with this.

Vue function:

```
methods: {
    submit() {
        axios.post('/login', this.fields)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                // Hier comes 'welcome message' 
                toastr()->success('you are logged in');
                }
            }).catch(error => {
            if (error.response.status === 401) {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error from the console of your browser? I guess you should try 'this.toastr().success("success")'

Comment: @AliBabaAzimi sorry for my late response! no it does not work
 'this.toastr()->error("Your verification in Expired.")'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem! :-)

In laravel controllers this package works fine for me.

```
composer require yoeunes/toastr
```

To make toastr Global so it works in Vue.js as well, I have installed toastr package via npm as follow!

```
npm install toastr --save
npm run dev
```

Then I have registered it in bootstrap.js

```
window.toastre = require('toastr');
```

and then I could call him in my vue axios function!

```
methods: {
   submit() {
      axios.post('/login', this.fields)
         .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
               this.fields = {};
               this.errors = {};
               this.success = true;
               toastr.success('you are logged in');
               
           }
        }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
           this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
        }
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Mohsen thanks for using the package, and you are right in your comments, "yoeunes/toastr" was not created to show notification from your JS code, I'm happy you found a solution for the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare a global variable and assign 'this' to it because whenever you call 'this' inside your axios it refers to response. Then, call the declared gloabal variable inside your axios function:

```
methods: {
    submit() {
        var gloabl_this = this;
        axios.post('/login', this.fields)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                // Hier comes 'welcome message' 
                global_this.toastr()->success('you are logged in');
                }
            }).catch(error => {
            if (error.response.status === 401) {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you, and please let me know if it still gives any error.

Comment: No it does not work! I do not get any errors! yoeunes/toastr package is meant voor Laravel but I want to use that in Vue.js too!

Comment: Try to use the toaster function in the first line of your submit function, just before axios function, and see weather it works or not. If it doesnt work the problems is somewhere else, but if it works the error belongs to axios.